# locationManager.stopUpdateLocations не работает после выхода из background

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Использую отслеживание геопозиции в фоновом режиме, после нескольких минут когда приложение находится в фоновом режиме перестает работать вызов locationManager.stopUpdateLocations() - синяя полоса сверху не убирается и приложение продолжает использовать службы геопозиции (причем даже если всего один раз свернуть приложение после запуска геолокации). Если выполнить вызов locationManager.stopUpdateLocations() ни разу не сворачивая приложение в фоновый режим (или если свернуть приложение на очень короткий промежуток времени 1-2 минуты) - то службы выключаются и синяя полоса сверху исчезает. Кто с этим сталкивался, помогите, потратил уже несколько дней - все безрезультатно. Отключил всю логику, осталось только: запуск служб геолокации (locationManager.startUpdateLocations) и попытка остановки( locationManager.stopUpdateLocations). Никаких таймеров и вообще никакой другой логики.

Вот код класса с геолокацией:

```
import CoreLocation

final class MyLocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    

    func sendCoord() {
        print("Send you coordinates")
    }
    
    func requestPermission() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func start() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 300
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        sendCoord()
        
    }
    
    func stop() {

        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = false
        locationManager.delegate = nil 
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    
        sendCoord()
    }
}
```

Вот код класса ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    // *** Internal variables *** //
    private let locationService = MyLocationService()
    var needPermissionForLocationServices = false

    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var startLocationToolBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    @IBAction func startLocationToolBarButtonAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

            switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {

                case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
           
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Location services is off", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to settings?", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                print("")
                            UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)! as URL)
                        }))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                    
                case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:

                    locationService.start()
                  
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    if action.lRefresh {
                        refreshAfterAction(action: action)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Location services is off", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to settings?", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                print("")
                    UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)! as URL)
                    }))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
                locationService.requestPermission()
            }
         
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var stopLocationToolBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    @IBAction func stopLocationToolBarButtonAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        locationService.stop()
         
    }
    
    // *** View Controller Functions *** //
    
    deinit {
        print("Deinit: VC NO MEMORY LEAKS")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        locationService.requestPermission()
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Нужно было просто создать shared instance для класса MyLocationService и не создавать в ViewController экземпляр этого класса в виде переменной, а вызывать один и тот же синглтон. Причина была в том что я создавал разные экземпляры класса MyLocationService и запускал локацию в одном экземпляре а остановить пытался в другом.

```
class var sharedInstance: MyLocationService {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = MyLocationService()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
}
```

А вызывать методы так:

```
MyLocationService.sharedInstance.start()
```